# Is there a pandas method to find the 4th 5-quantile of a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, data-science

I was recently trying to solve a data science test. Part of the test was to get the number of observations in a dataset for which the variable X is less than the 4th 5-quantile of this variable X.
I don't realy understand what they meant by the 4th 5-quantile! I tried using pandas df.quantile function but I wasn't able to figure out how to use it in my case

Comment: compute the `0.6` and `0.8` quantile. Then filter values between those two?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But do you mind to explain why?  How does that translate to  "less than the 4th 5-quantile"?

Answer (score 0):

4th 5-quantile translates `value = data.quantile(4/5)`